module not found al correr npm run dev
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nicof\OneDrive\Escritorio\imperia hub\gestion-bodega-backend\index.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1249:15)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:27)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:170:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:36:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v22.11.0.

este es el error que me da al iniciar el comando. estoy usando node.js para hacer una prueba basica de conexion de base datos, el archivo index.js esta dentro de la carpeta src y el package.json en la seccion de script tengo esto "start": "node Index.js",
"dev": "nodemon Index.js" dado que estoy usando la dependencia de nodemon.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Saca el espacio en el nombre de carpeta y se va a arreglar todo magicamente
